# Title text color of action is not changing and how to change the title text color of action bar

Tags: android

Title text color of action is not changing and how to change the title text color of action bar? and here is my `style.xml` code

**style.xml**

[image]

Comment: That screenshot xD have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5881739/284308

Comment: Could you post your code or layouts as text?

Answer (score 0):

As @Sunny answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45879575/6914992) from my question [What is the difference between colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark in themes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45879513/6914992). Try to change colors through this in your themes .

- colorPrimary – The color of the app bar.
- colorPrimaryDark – The color of the status bar and contextual app bars; this is normally a dark version of colorPrimary.
- colorAccent – The color of UI controls such as check boxes, radio buttons, and edit text boxes.
- windowBackground – The color of the screen background.
- textColorPrimary – The color of UI text in the app bar.
- statusBarColor – The color of the status bar.
- navigationBarColor – The color of the navigation bar.

you can use following link to setup your style.

https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/

**NOTE** Please upvote sunny's answer if it helps rather than this, thanks