# Trying to understand Theme.MaterialComponents

Tags: android, angular-material, material-design, material-components-android

I moved recently from `Theme.AppCompat` to `Theme.MaterialComponents` but I can't understand how to orgnaize colors.

```
<style name="Theme.Test" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/orange</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/yellow</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/green</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

For example why buttons take orange background color but background of cardview not take orange color?

Can someone explain to me more about these variables `colorPrimary , colorPrimaryVariant , colorOnPrimary , colorSecondary , colorSecondaryVariant and colorOnSecondary`

Is there any offical documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the following documentation: https://material.io/develop/android/theming/color

- **colorPrimary**: The color displayed most frequently across your app’s screens and components. This color should pass accessibilty guidelines for text / iconography when drawn on top of the surface or background color.
- **colorPrimaryVariant**: A tonal variation of the primary color.
- **colorOnPrimary**: A color that passes accessibility guidelines for text/iconography when drawn on top of the primary color.
- **colorSecondary**: The secondary branding color for the app, usually an accented complement to the primary branding color.
- **colorSecondaryVariant**: A tonal variation of the secondary color.
- **colorOnSecondary**: A color that passes accessibility guidelines for text/iconography when drawn on top of the secondary color.

You can also refer to this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45879575/9246764

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for specifics about each component, the [material.io](https://material.io) documentation usually provides information about the default values for various attributes.

For example, the documentation for [`MaterialCardView`](https://material.io/components/cards/android#card) specifies that the default `app:cardBackgroundColor` is `?attr/colorSurface`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the material sites official docs on using these themes in Android

https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started

Comment: But I still don't know what the variables above does

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you should now use components from the Material theme.
For example if you just want to Use a textview and apply the material theme on it
You should be using it the way they suggest.
For example for the textview you should use it

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="First Name"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    app:hintTextColor="@color/black">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/fName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

I think you are not using the card view from the material theme.
Just check the official doc.
https://material.io/components/cards