# What is the difference between colorPrimary and colorSecondary in android themes

Tags: android, user-interface, styles, themes

I want to use the colorPrimary and colorSecondary in proper way.

A good example with image will be great help for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark in themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45879513/what-is-the-difference-between-colorprimary-and-colorprimarydark-in-themes)

Comment: I have seen the second answer. I am trying to get an answer of having a good example for colorSecondary usage. Thank you @javdromero, second answer is

Answer (score 0):

I have found a material for coloring. This is awesome.

**Picking colors**

Figuring out which color values to use for each slot may be the responsibility of a designer, or derived from your product’s brand. However, it’s still useful to know about the role of each color, the relationship between them, and how to meet accessibility requirements:

**colorPrimary** and **colorSecondary** represent the colors of your brand
colorPrimaryVariant and colorSecondaryVariant are lighter or darker shades of your brand colors
colorSurface is used for “sheets” of material (like cards and bottom sheets)
android:colorBackground is the window background color of your app
colorError is, as the name suggests, for errors and warnings
The various “On” colors (colorOnPrimary, colorOnSecondary, colorOnSurface, etc.) are used to tint foreground content (such as text and icons) displayed on top of the other colors. They need to meet accessibility requirements and have sufficient contrast against the colors they’re displayed on.

https://material.io/blog/android-material-theme-color